# Is Santa more than fiction in the Harry Potter Universe?

Tags: harry-potter, jk-rowling, santa-claus

We know that the Potterians (Potterites?, Potterlings?) celebrate Christmas (at least they do in the UK).

**Are there mentions of Santa?** Is/was he some sort of real person.
In the same way we (out of universe) consider Merlin to be fictional,  JK has co-opted him as a historical figure (in universe ).

He is certainly  [mentioned](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Father_Christmas) but this doesn't address whether he's  'real'.

Somewhat related, but doesn't answer my question:
[Did J. K. Rowling's Religious Beliefs Determine Much in Harry Potter?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9133/did-j-k-rowlings-religious-beliefs-determine-much-in-harry-potter?rq=1)

Comment: Based on a brief book text search and the absence of any other Wikia info, I'm tempted to say "no".

Comment: @DVK - are you saying no to the mention of Santa or no to JK's religious beliefs? :D I can't recall any mention of Santa in any canon/interviews from JK, but I vaguely recall JK mentioning that her religious beliefs did impact the HP series, i will have to find the interview/quote, unless Slytherincess/DVK can throw in a comment? :D

Comment: Slightly related is the question http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/53242/ When did using a fireplace as a portal first become used?

Comment: @BP_Phoenix - no Santa. No Tooth Fairy either.

Comment: Well, it'd make sense if Santa _were_ a wizard. 1) He'd probably use the Floo Network to visit all those houses so fast (and to muggles it'd look like he'd used the chimney), 2) he'd use a bag like Hermione's that is bigger on the inside to carry all those toys, 3) house elves make the toys in his workshop, etc.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Father Christmas is [referenced](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Father_Christmas) in four out of the seven Harry Potter books but there's no canon confirmation (in the text, at least) that he's viewed as anything other than *mythological* even to the Wizarding world.

In general his name is used in much the same way that modern British people would use it, e.g. to describe someone jolly, fat, bearded and prone to giving out presents, the literal living embodiment of the Christmas spirit.

For the record, the original Santa Claus/Father Christmas was [almost certainly a real person](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Santa_Claus#Predecessor_figures) (for a given value of "real") which neatly answers the question of whether he's fictional in the wizard world.

Comment: He was probably a wizard to them, too, from what they say about other people who we assume were "Muggles" with legends built up around them.

Comment: @DalekLuna - Very possibly.

Comment: @DalekLuna That is what I assumed, but wanted to know if there was any evidence.

Comment: I always thought Santa was the American version of Father Christmas but they aren't quite the same

Comment: @DannyMcG Like the Greek and Roman pantheons, they're often equated.