# How does Narnia's Father Christmas work?

Tags: character-development, the-chronicles-of-narnia, santa-claus

While reading [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/53774/is-santa-more-than-fiction-in-the-harry-potter-universe), I began to wonder how Santa/Father Christmas works according to the *Narnia* series.

- We know he's a *real* person (since the children meet him in the first published book)
- We know we he has what appear to be reindeer and a sleigh
- We know he gives gifts (at least to the children in that scene anyway)

There a lot of questions this brings up though, like is this the same Santa as in *our* world (and he's delivers both to Narnia *and* our world) or is this just Narnia's Santa? How does he enter and exit Narnia?

#### **How does Narnia's Father Christmas work?**

<sub>I realize there might not be much canon info available so some speculation is fine.</sub>

Comment: IIRC C.S Lewis was writing a thinly veiled Christian story. Santa is exactly as in the real world.

Comment: Agree with the above comments: given that a certain character is revealed to be a transcendent being that can traverse between worlds, it is not unreasonable to see Father Christmas as a similarly divine entity that has a purpose / role in every world.

Comment: He probably uses the Narnia/Earth time difference to visit all those houses in one night.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## He probably is the same Santa from our world

Taking a look at [the movie script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Chronicles-of-Narnia-The-Lion,-the-Witch-and-the-Wardrobe.html), you will note that he actually refers to Lucy **by her own name** (emphasis mine):

> Father Christmas stands there.
>
> LUCY:  Merry Christmas, Sir!
>
> FATHER CHRISTMAS: It certainly is, **Lucy**. Thanks to you.

He does the same in the book:

> "Peter, Adam's son," said Father Christmas.
> ...
> "Susan, Eve's daughter," said Father Christmas. "These are for you"
> ...
> Last of all he said, "Lucy, Eve's daughter," and Lucy came forward.
> *Chapter Ten, The Spell Begins to Break*

Every other character (aside from Aslan) refers to them solely as Daughters or Sons of Eve.  How would Santa know their names if he was confined to Narnia?  I take this as evidence that Santa is the same as from our world.

## How does he move between the worlds?

By Magic of Course!  Seriously though, we know that there is more than one way to travel to Narnia:

- The wardrobe from *The Lion, The Witch and The Wardrobe*
- Aslan's magic
- The Forest Between the Worlds

It stands to reason that Santa could use any of these (although I somehow doubt the wardrobe), or even his own magic possibly.

Comment: A movie script? **Sacrilege!**

Comment: "How would Santa know Lucy's name if he was confined to Narnia?" Well, how would he know it in any case?

Comment: @JonKiparsky Santa knows everyone's names - he's Santa!

Answer (score 14):

### Who's to say Father Christmas even exists in our world?

Certainly (spoilers!) in the *real* world he doesn't, and Lewis's depiction of our world seems pretty realistic, except of course for the gateways to Narnia. So I think this Father Christmas is a good spirit of Narnia alone.

In the Christian-allegory version of Lewis's fantasy story, he is the **John the Baptist** to the Jesus represented by Aslan: first he arrives, and the Lord Aslan swiftly follows.

Comment: 1) spoilers! lol. 2) I think Lewis is actually saying that Santa exists _in-universe_ and can normally visit Narnia ([except during the 100 year winter](http://narnia.wikia.com/wiki/Father_Christmas)) and 3) I really like the parallel you drew between Narnia's Santa and John the Baptist, I'd never thought of that!

Comment: Note that the general consensus is that Santa is in fact real; https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1018/20774

Comment: _in the real world he doesn't_ I think you will can find an extremely high percentage of 3 - 10 year olds (Europe and North America) who will vouch safe for the existence of Santa. So be careful of touting your own opinion as fact. I'd say well North of 90%.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is the same Santa, assuming he can travel through the worlds the same way the kids can. It is also stated there are many different hidden passages in and out of Narnia, so he probably leaves and enters through those.

Answer (score 1):

Could Father Christmas be a star? Like Coriakin and Ramandu in the Voyage of the Dawn Treader?
It would clear up why he is only truly seen in Narnia where other 'figments of man's myths and imaginations' (such as fauns and unicorns) exist for real, why he has the powers that he does,why he always appears to be an old, white-bearded man, and why he recognizes Aslan as the true king.
Aslan could've made him into Father Christmas after Frank and Helen introduced Christmas to the Narnians after they became king and queen in the Magician's Nephew.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You should write this as an answer, and not start by asking a question.  This is a question-and-answer site, not a discussion site, so you should not expect responses to your answer.  Please write the most solid, complete and definitive answer you can, instead of proposing ideas for discussion.  You might want to take the [tour].